# Unable to invoke functions from referenced dll

Tags: .net, vb.net

[image]

I have referenced a DLL and can access methods/functions therein without any errors. The issue arises when I build the project. I get an error that says 'not defined', although my referenced method is valid and I can *Peek Definition*. I closed and opened *Visual Studio*, restated PC, deleted Temp items, climbed a tree etc (all in vain). Could someone please assist. I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: You have 20 warnings, perhaps one of them can tell you something useful if you don't hide them. Do you also have the proper `Imports` statements?

Comment: Might be some CLS-compliance problem? Try to create new C# Project and use your DLL in that.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes I have _Imports_ statements that is why the method is showing in blue.

Comment: Maybe the DLL is not carried along in the build path?

Comment: The issue was 1, the target framework for the dll was higher than that of the current project. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target dot Net framework was incompatible. Solution was to upgrade my project.